# Send Email To The Customer On Order Complete in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am having problems with my Wordpress installation, or WooCommerce to be more specific.

The client I've been working for the last couple of months, wants that every time a customer completes/pays an order, a custom email is sent to his email address, besides the standard order confirmation email.

In short: **I need to send a custom email to the customer when the order is completed.
How can I do that inside the functions.php?**

I tried using various hooks and functions described in the official documentation, but couldn't figure it out.

The Wordpress version is 3.8.1, and WooCommerce is version is 2.0.20.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem. I was using the wrong hook all the time. That's the main reason for the problems. The correct hook name was "**woocommerce_thankyou**". After I changed the functions to use this hook, everything went just right.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by using action called [woocommerce_payment_complete](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/);

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

function order_completed( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $to_email = $order["billing_address"];
    $headers = 'From: Your Name <your@email.com>' . "\r\n";
    wp_mail($to_email, 'subject', 'message', $headers );

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'order_completed' );
```

Comment: Tried the function, but it doesn't seem to work form some reason. The answer seems correct, the action name is also documented, but I just can't receive the email.

Comment: @Alessio If you are developing your own plugin, you should put this on your plugin actions.

Comment: no I was only trying to do some actions after the order was completed, I've put this code in the functions.php file inside my theme folder, but it's not called...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not retrieving mail due to Three main reasons

1. SMTP Plugin needed to be configured correclty if it is anabled
2. Try PHP mail function as `mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);`
3. Add priority to action being added as `add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'order_completed',1 );`

Comment: I doubt that, because all other mail functions are working properly. Wordpress/WooCommerce is sending other emails correctly (order confirmation and order processed emails). I think that's not causing the problem.